# Flutter - How to loop through nested collection and convert to DataTable row?

Tags: database, flutter, dart, datatable

So I have this DB structure:
[image]

I need to get all the sets for a every exercise for a workout for a user and then display it in a DataTable.

```
      StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("workouts")
          .doc(workoutId)
          .collection("exercises")
          .snapshots(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return const Text("There are no exercises");
        }

        return DataTable(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(
              width: 2,
              color: kBlack,
            ),
          ),
          dataRowHeight: SizeConfig.screenHeight * 0.05,
          dataTextStyle: const TextStyle(
              fontSize: kAppButtonTextFontSize, color: kAppTextColor),
          headingRowHeight: SizeConfig.screenHeight * 0.05,
          headingTextStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: kAppButtonTextFontSize),
          //horizontalMargin,
          columnSpacing: 20,
          showCheckboxColumn: true,
          showBottomBorder: false,
          dividerThickness: 3,
          columns: const [
            DataColumn(
              label: Text(
                "Set#",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                  color: kBlack,
                ),
              ),
              numeric: true,
            ),
            DataColumn(
              label: Text(
                "Weight",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                  color: kBlack,
                ),
              ),
              numeric: true,
              //tooltip: "This is Last Name",
            ),
            DataColumn(
              label: Text(
                "Reps",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                  color: kBlack,
                ),
              ),
              numeric: true,
            ),
            DataColumn(
              label: Text(
                "ToFailure",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                  color: kBlack,
                ),
              ),
              numeric: true,
            ),
          ],
          rows: _getExercises(snapshot),// Here I want to get the rows
        );
      });


    _getExercises(AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
  setState(() {

//How to structure the data here so as to get DataRows

    snapshot.data!.docs.forEach((doc) {
      //print(
     //   'DOCUMENT DATA =' + doc.data().toString(),
     // );
      completedExerciseSetRows.add(
        DataRow(cells: [
          DataCell(Text()),
          
          DataCell(Text()),
          
          DataCell(Text()),

        ]),
      );
    });
  });
```

[image]

Comment: it would be helpful if you provided your data model class or classes (if you have em) and the image of how your DataTable would look like. i had solved a similar case, i hope i can be of help

Comment: I don't have a model class, it's not required for this.I have added the image of how the datatable has to look.